# manage controlller's method parameter in codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

Here my  method

```
public function sale($id,$type){
   if($id==TRUE){
       .....................
       .....................
    }
    if($type==TRUE){
      .......................
      .......................
    }
}
```

I want Browse two parameter individually, suppose

> http://mysite.com/mycontroller/sale/id

and

> http://mysite.com/mycontroller/sale/type

How can it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
URL Format : http://mysite.com/mycontroller/sale/id ( not possible )
NOW : http://mysite.com/mycontroller/sale/selector/id/value/1
NOW : http://mysite.com/mycontroller/sale/selector/type/value/1

```
function sale(){
   $type    = $this->uri->segment(4);  #get the selector
   $val     = $this->uri->segment(6);  #get the value
   if( $type == "id" ){
        #in id selection
   }else if( $type == "type" ){
      #in type selection
   }else{
        redirect('somewhere', 'refresh');
   }
}
```

Comment: but you don't use any parameter why?

Comment: Cause we get the parameter(s) inside the controller function using the CI default segment style. Try and let me know if it worked for you or not.

Comment: yes, yes, yes,  it works and sorry for let, you are awesome. It work well but every time I need extra two words(sector, value). but no problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multi-params with URL:

For example following urls:

```
http://mysite.com/mycontroller/sale

http://mysite.com/mycontroller/sale/3

http://mysite.com/mycontroller/sale/3/computer
```

Here codes:

```
public function sale($id = false, $type = false) {

   if($id) {
       // something to do
   }

   if($type) {
      // something to do
   }
}
```